# How is this resistor different from the more common resistors?

Tags: resistors, identification

What is difference between this resistor in a glass capsule with filler in red color and another color of line at an middle or end and the more common ones?

[image]

https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1uQElKpXXXXbzXFXXq6xXFXXXl/MTG1-NTC-glass-resistor.jpg_Q90.jpg_.webp

Answer (score 7):

The ones in your photo appear to be glass-packaged NTC (Negative Temperature Coefficient) [thermistors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermistor).

A thermistor is a resistor that has a predictable change in resistance with temperature.  Since they are resistive they require no polarity markings.

The glass package make them more suitable for use at high temperatures. They typically change in resistance by about -4% per degree C. [Here](https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/LFSI/LFSI-S-A0012730375/LFSI-S-A0012730375-1.pdf) is a datasheet of similar parts from a well-known supplier with detailed specifications.

[image]

Positive temperature coefficient silicon resistors are also available in that package.

A similar package is used for semiconductors such as signal diodes, zener diodes, diacs, current regulator diodes etc., most of which have polarity so they will have a band at one end (and sometimes color bands like a resistor to indicate part number or whatever).

Comment: NTC Thermistor labeled R ?

it's what the real case i witnessed.

Comment: Maybe a translation issue. The Chinese for thermistor is more like "heat sensitive resistor" (not a special word like thermistor) so NTC resistor makes sense.

Comment: I have on occasion found a resistor replaced with an NTC as a rework. Also I've quite often seen these parts identified on PCBs as RT, so it would not be a total stretch to find one of these labelled as R...

Answer (score 1):

The most important difference is that while for most resistors the resistance increases slightly with temperature, in the case of NTC devices the resistance drops as temperature rises.  They are typically used in situations where the circuit’s characteristics need to change with temperature, such as in battery chargers or fan control circuits.